# Python printing bytes strangely

Tags: python

So, I have this very simple code:

```
from construct import VarInt

a = VarInt.build(12345)
print(a)
with open('hello.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(a)
```

When I print "a", it shows only the first byte and the last byte for some reason does not show properly. It prints "b'\xb9`'" and it should print "b'\xb9\x60'", or at least that's what I would like to print. Now, when I look at the file that I stored, it saves the bytes exactly how it should with no issue there. Does anybody know what's going on here? Also, with some integers it prints properly, but with this one, for example, does not.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: If the file does not contain plain text, it should not use a `.txt` file extension. This smacks of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single byte but

```
b'\xb9`'
```

Do You see "`" after `9`? It's a character encoded as `0x60`. If You want to display all bytes as hexadecimal You can try this snippet:

```
print(" ".join(hex(n) for n in a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that is does not print properly? Assuming an ASCII derived code page(ASCII, UTF-8 or latin), the code for the back quote (`) is 96  or 0x60.

As `\xb9` does not map to a character in your system code page, it is escaped, but as `\x60` does map to the back quote, the representation just uses that character.